# Find the Average Rank

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Anyone can help me to find the average of the ranking.

```
SELECT datetime, resource_id, ipaddress, sysname, resource_name,cpu_utilization, cpu_service_interrupt_utilization, rank
FROM ( SELECT datetime, resource_id, ipaddress, sysname, resource_name, cpu_utilization, cpu_service_interrupt_utilization, 
dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sysname,resource_name ORDER BY cpu_utilization DESC) AS rank
FROM ip_cpu_mn
WHERE date_trunc('hour',datetime) = date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp - interval '1 hour')  
and sysname ='ag-01-glsfb-re0' and resource_name like '%1 slot'
order by sysname, resource_name, datetime
) AS A
where rank <4
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Actually, the objective is to find average on the 3 highest cpu utilization in 1 hour according to the sysname, resource name.                                   To easy for me for now, I set the ranking and the second action is to find the average of the rank. I am lacking of idea and  need to improve the code.

Comment: Yes , find the average in that select. Is that possible ?

Comment: You need to use group by to achieve that, So you want to get avg of all rows that retuned by query or what??

Comment: Forgive me if the word is confusing. I need to have the average of the top ranking ( from output result ) . My expected result will be in 1 row . I want to amend the query above by put average ( of the top highest cpu utlization ) .

Comment: Yes really confused me .. and check - http://hastebin.com/koyobuguto.sql

Comment: The objective is to find the Average of the 3 highest cpu utilization in 1 hour according to the sysname, resource name. Actually, my friend recommend me to find the rank ( to find the highest cpu)  and then set the average of the highest cpu, that's why my code looks incomplete.  I am testing the code recommended by you.

Comment: Check this - http://hastebin.com/fehipudoka.sql